# AVConv loop issue with output file names

Tags: media, convert, avconv, batch

How can I turn:

```
/media/MediaOne/Movies/Kids/Aladdin.avi
/media/MediaOne/Movies/Kids/Incredibles.avi
```

into

```
/media/MediaOne/converted/Aladdin.mp4
/media/MediaOne/converted/Incredibles.mp4
```

when looping a directory using avconv?

Right now, they are outputted as:

```
/media/MediaOne/Movies/Kids/Aladdin.avi.mp4
/media/MediaOne/Movies/Kids/Incredibles.avi.mp4
```

and here is what I am trying:

```
for i in /media/MediaOne/Movies/Kids/*.avi; do avconv -i "$i" -c copy "$i.mp4"; done
```

tried this too:

```
for i in /media/MediaOne/Movies/Kids/*.avi; do avconv -i "$i" -c copy "/media/MediaOne/converted/$i.mp4"; done
```

but got a bunch of errors, because $i/media/MediaOne/converted/ did not exist

Comment: tried i%, but the files were named i%.mp4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `basename` command to remove extension from file name, notice special quotation marks

```
`$(basename $i .avi).mp4`
```

instead of

```
"$i.mp4"
```

`dirname` may help to extract path to folder containing input file. (`man dirname` for help)